# Sum of infinite series - Catalan constant

Tags: sequences-and-series, constants, catalans-constant

Why is this identity true?
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(k\pi/2)}{k^2} = G$$
where $G$ is Catalan's constant.

Comment: Hint: What is the definition of the Catalan constant, and what does the sequence of numbers $\sin(k\pi / 2)$ look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The series sums to $$\frac{1}{1^2}-\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{5^2}-\cdots$$ which is just the definition of [Catalan's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant).